# How can I deal with mass texts from an Apple phone when using an Android phone?

Tags: sms

Occasionally one of my friends using an iPhone will send out a mass text, and for the next few days I get spammed with texts from all the other numbers they sent it to, most of them unidentified on my phone, and since some of them are responding to each other, none of them make any sense. It's incredibly annoying. Presumably iPhones have something that can detect and properly order mass texts, as Apple wouldn't want to annoy their own users, only Android users. Is there something I can do to make the mass text make more sense on my end?

Comment: What's your end goal, organize the emails? move them to a specific location? ignore them? trash them? Sorry but I don't get the *"make more sense on my end"* :/

Comment: @Zuul - It's not emails, it's text messages. Apparently Apple recently added some mass text thing, where you can send out messages to a whole group of people, and they all appear, along with their responses, in a single conversation. As well, when any of them responds, it goes to everyone else the original message was sent to. At least, I'm guessing that's how it works. As I'm on an android phone, all these messages don't get put together, instead each person is in their own conversation, so the messages don't make any sense without flipping between conversations checking the timestamps.

Comment: Which app do you use to read your text messages? And btw, do you know which app your friends use?

Comment: I'm just using the default Android Messaging app. And I'm pretty sure they're using the default iOS Messaging app. The mass text thing is part of iOS.

Comment: By "mass texts", do you mean Iphone's group texting?

Comment: @JaredBurrows - Yes.

Comment: That is very strange. I just recently got the HTC Droid DNA and it supports group texting, so my phone gets along with iPhones.

Comment: I suspect newer ones support it. When I asked this, I was using a Samsung Galaxy S. I recently got an S3, but I haven't had an opportunity to see how it handles group texts.

Comment: Maybe use [Whatsapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) or [Viber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip)?

Comment: @JaredBurrows HTC will have modified the SMS app to support it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jelly Bean](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/) upgrade (4.2) add support for group messaging.
So, two solutions :

- upgrade your phone to Jelly Bean 4.2.
- install a third party application that handles it : [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.powow) seems to have a fair number of good reviews.