# Text Messaging: Group Text Message

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms

I  have a DroidX running Android 2.3.4.  When somebody sends me a text message that goes to other devices too, is there anyway I can tell?  Usually the only way I find out is when somebody else does a "reply all" (probably using a newer version of Android), and I get some random message from a number I may or may not recognize.

Also, what about when I reply to the message?  Does it only go to the person who sent it to me, or does it somehow auto-reply-all behind the scenes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deal with mass texts from an Apple phone when using an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27536/how-can-i-deal-with-mass-texts-from-an-apple-phone-when-using-an-android-phone)

Comment: @t0mm13b It does sound similar.  However, this is not just an Apple to Android thing.  This also happens Android to Android.

Comment: They are very different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on 2.3.5

In the basic "messages" app you can go to the message, clicknhold, view message details. There it shows all recipients.

If i just reply it only goes back to the sender. Now, others that I know have iphones replied and it went to everyone...

There is a "reply all" option after you click and hold.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could press and hold and see who the message was sent to.  Interesting though that there isn't an icon or something to even indicate when that message was sent to multiple recipients...

Answer (score 3):

In 4.2.1 (maybe in 4.2.0) there was an option added to the MMS application to support multiple recipients.

While you may have been able to see them all the way that William stated, i've never seen that option.

In 4.2.1 you click on the menu and select "Group Participants". This shows everyone that is included in the conversation. When you reply to a group now, it sends the messages to all participants, not just the person that sent you the message.

I know this doesn't relate directly to your question as you are not asking about 4.2, but I do not know of a way that this can be done in anything pre-4.2. This feature was discussed a bit because it was the first time android supported this feature.

While you could always "start" a group conversation in any version of android, you could not "participate" in a group conversation with anyone other than the original sender.

[image: Groups] [image: Groups 2]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the stock messaging service by adding numbers seperated by a comma into the recipient box.

But in my opinion there's a better option. You can download [**GroupMe**](https://groupme.com/android) which let's you message multiple people at a time. You can choose whether to use SMS or your data connection to send the message.